# Too many re-renders in react when using useReducer Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm facing a weird problem when using the useReducer react hook, I know the origin of the error, but I don't know why it occurs in my code.

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react'

import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'


export default function User() {

const initialState = {
    lowScore: 0,
    mediumScore: 0,
    hightScore: 0 
}

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'LOW':
            return {
                ...state,
                lowScore: state.lowScore + 1
            }
        case 'MEDIUM':
            return {
                ...state,
                mediumScore: state.mediumScore + 1
            }
        case 'HIGH':
            return {
                ...state,
                hightScore: state.hightScore + 1
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)

return (
    <div>
        Low: { state.lowScore }, medium: { state.mediumScore }, hight: { state.hightScore } 
        <Button onClick={dispatch('LOW')}>Increment low</Button>
        <Button >Increment medium</Button>
        <Button >Increment hight</Button>
    </div>
)
}
```

I dispatch the action only when the user click on the buttons, so I can't figure out how it causes multiples renders.

Any explanation would be precious

Comment: A component will rerender when: 1) its props change, 2) its state changes, 3) its parent component rerenders. It's hard to diagnose which one of those 3 it can be from the code you have provided (other than the dispatch actions you have shown)

Comment: @rantao The dispatch action will update the state, so why it's hard to know which one causes the rerender ?

Comment: I'm saying there is more than one reason as to why you're component could be rerendering, and you're only showing code that identifies one of the three reasons

Comment: @ⵍⵢⴻⵙ Did the below answer solve your problem? If so, please choose it as the correct answer (click the checkmark beside the answer) in order to close out this question and award reputation points. That would help us out. Otherwise, please add a comment under the answer OR update your question with more information and others will attempt to assist. *Many thanks!*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you render component. You have called function `dispath` without any click. You should pass a call back to event onClick:

Updated correctly action make it work:

```
   <Button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'LOW'})}>Increment low</Button>
```

Comment: And to make it work you should dispatch an object with property type - `() => dispatch({type:'LOW'})`

Comment: @VietDinh my bad, thank you, I still don't understand the react's behaviour, does `dispatch('LOW')` cause multiple rerenders ?

Comment: when rendering component. You have add result of function dispath('LOW') into event lick. That function will be called. And then dispath will return a new state for component. If no change in return state function component will be not re-rendered. But, react may have syntax detection some case will make infinity loop as 'always call setState' in return function. Your case, it always call dispath.

Comment: I just ran into this same issue, is there any documentation about this behavior.